# Prevent var from going negative

Tags: javascript, html, button, var

I have a button with a var that start with a 0 and when you click a another button it increases to 1. But if you click the second button first, the var goes negative. The button is disabled at the beginning, but when it increases to 1 the button should be enabled.

When the page is loaded the button disabled, but when the var goes to 1 the button is still disabled.
I tried: `if(var == 0){document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true; return false;}`

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: <anotherButton disabled={var ===0} />

Comment: Are you using "plain" javascript with static html and css? Please show us at least a [minimal, reproducible example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to give an example but the code i wrote didnt work. The code below works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like in below snippet :

> You can use any tag instead of `input` like `div` `span` `h1` ... which ever you wish and style according to need .
> This thing you will need to change will be change `.value` to `.innerHTML` everywhere like this(1 example) :
> `var units = document.getElementsByClassName("unitsMain")[0].innerHTML`

```js
function decreaseUnits() {
  var units = document.getElementsByClassName("unitsMain")[0].value
  if (units > 0) {
    units--;
    document.getElementsByClassName("unitsMain")[0].value = units;
  }
}

function increaseUnits() {
  var units = document.getElementsByClassName("unitsMain")[0].value
  units++;
  document.getElementsByClassName("unitsMain")[0].value = units;
}
```

```html
<button class="decOrderUnits" onclick="decreaseUnits()"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>-</button>
<input class="unitsMain" value="0" maxlength="3">
<button class="incOrderUnits" onclick="increaseUnits()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>+</button>
```